# Array of Matrices in Python

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

as the title says, I'm trying to define a array of matrices (witch represents images) in Python. But, when I try to read a matrix, I got this message: "ImageData instance has no attribute '**getitem**'""
I'm starting to study Python these days, so I know that this must be simple for a lot of people, but I don't know what's wrong. This is my code:

## ImageData.py

```
import random
import math

class ImageData:

def __init__ (self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.data = []
    for i in range(width):
        self.data.append([0] * height)

def set_data (self, x, y, value):
    self.data[x][y] = value

def generate_voronoi_diagram (self, seeds):
    nx = []
    ny = []
    nr = []
    ng = []
    nb = []
    for i in range(seeds):
        # Generate a cell position
        pos_x = random.randrange(self.width)
        pos_y = random.randrange(self.height)
        nx.append(pos_x)
        ny.append(pos_y)

        # Save the rgb data
        nr.append(random.randrange(256))
        ng.append(random.randrange(256))
        nb.append(random.randrange(256))

    for x in range(self.width):
        for y in range(self.height):
            # Return the Euclidean norm
            d_min = math.hypot(self.width-1, self.height-1)
            j = -1
            for i in range(seeds):
                # The distance from a cell to x, y point being considered
                d = math.hypot(nx[i]-x, ny[i]-y)
                if d < d_min:
                    d_min = d
                    j = i
                self.data[x][y] = [nr[j], ng[j], nb[j]]
```

## UncertaintyVisualisaton.py

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy
import ImageData

def generate_uncertainty_visualisation (images, width, height):
    image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
    putpixel = image.putpixel
    r = g = b = []
    for i in range(width):
        r.append([0] * height)
        g.append([0] * height)
        b.append([0] * height)
    for i in range(len(images)):
        image = images[i]
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                #Error here
                rgb = image[x][y]
                r[x][y] += rgb[0]
                g[x][y] += rgb[1]
                b[x][y] += rgb[2]
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(height):
            r[x][y] /= len(images)
            g[x][y] /= len(images)
            b[x][y] /= len(images)
            putpixel((x, y), (r[x][y], g[x][y], b[x][y]))
    image.save("output.png", "PNG")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    width = 10;
    height = 10;
    entries = []
    seeds = numpy.random.poisson(20)
    images = 1
    for n in range(images):
        entry = ImageData.ImageData(width, height)
        entry.generate_voronoi_diagram(seeds)
        entries.append(entry)
    generate_uncertainty_visualisation(entries, width, height)
```

Any help would be very appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please paste the full stack trace. It tells you exactly what the problem is and where. Also you can do this in a fraction of the code and running time with NumPy...

Comment: Can you fix the indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UncertaintyVisualisaton.py` first you set:

```
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
```

And then looping over `images` you reassign:

```
image = images[i]
```

This is probably not want you want.

Also your error:

```
#Error here
rgb = image[x][y]
```

is happening because ImageData is not a list. The data attibute in it is:

```
#no more Error here
rgb = image.data[x][y]
```

Comment: Thank you. Stupid mistakes. Thank you very much.